# storing two xslt variables in 1 xslt variable

Tags: arrays, variables, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need help where I can store two xslt variables in 1 array like variable to be used later

```
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDeviceArray">
        <Item><xsl:value-of select="$edgeDev1" /></Item>
        <Item><xsl:value-of select="$edgeDev2" /></Item>
    </xsl:variable>
```

But the output of the above seems to be concatenation. I would like to refer later like edgeDeviceArray[1]...

Here is a (non-working) fragment of my stylesheet demonstrating what I am trying to do

```
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDev1"
        select="$deviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device[t:address=$edgeDev1IP]/t:name" />
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDev2"
        select="$deviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device[t:address=$edgeDev2IP]/t:name" />
    <xsl:variable name="xrSet" select="$xrDeviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device-module/t:devices" />

    <xsl:for-each select="$xrSet">
      <xsl:variable name="asideDoc"
          select="document(concat($edgeDevice[position()], '.xml'))" />
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Here, I am reading the devices names from 1 doc based on certain attributes if they match.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
    xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
    xmlns:t="http://tail-f.com/ns/ncs"
    xmlns:x="http://tail-f.com/ns/config/1.0" 
    xmlns:y="http://tail-f.com/ned/alu-sr"
    xmlns:a="http://tail-f.com/ned/cisco-ios-xr"
    xmlns:m="http://mask.data"
    xmlns:im="http://inverse-mask.data" exclude-result-prefixes="xsl t x y"
    xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common" extension-element-prefixes="exsl">

  <xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"
      indent="yes" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="deviceDoc" select="document('devices.xml')" />
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDev1IP"
        select="../y:sdp[y:sdp-id=$sdpSet[1]]/y:far-end" />
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDev1"
        select="$deviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device[t:address=$edgeDev1IP]/t:name" />
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDev2IP"
        select="../y:sdp[y:sdp-id=$sdpSet[2]]/y:far-end" />
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDev2"
        select="$deviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device[t:address=$edgeDev2IP]/t:name" />
    <xsl:variable name="xrDeviceDoc" select="document('xrDevices.xml')" />
    <xsl:variable name="xrSet"
        select="$xrDeviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device-module/t:devices" />
    <xsl:variable name="edgeDeviceArray">
      <item><xsl:value-of select="$edgeDev1" /></item>
      <item><xsl:value-of select="$edgeDev2" /></item>
    </xsl:variable> 

    <anurag><xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($edgeDeviceArray)/item[1]" /></anurag>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Are you using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0?

Comment: I am using XSLT 1.0. Thx

Comment: You cannot do this in XSLT 1.0 without extensions, though you can get a close approximation if the two variables' values are node sets of one node each.  If you explain the purpose for which you wanted it, then perhaps we can suggest a better approach.

Comment: I have a loop where I want to refer the above devices and thats why I want to put them in some reference. I am reading the devices from different xml files and I store them in these two variables.

Comment: Thanks, @Anurag, but in order to help you, I think we are going to need to see a [mcve] demonstrating the problem.

Comment: <xsl:variable name="edgeDev1"
          select="$deviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device[t:address=$edgeDev1IP]/t:name" /> <xsl:variable name="edgeDev2"
          select="$deviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device[t:address=$edgeDev2IP]/t:name" /> <xsl:variable name="xrSet" select="$xrDeviceDoc/x:config/t:devices/t:device-module/t:devices" /> <xsl:for-each select="$xrSet">  Here is where I want to use the edgeDev1 and edgeDev2 based on the position()

Comment: @Anurag, please edit the MCVE into your question -- do not attempt to post it in comments.

Comment: Done. Added the snippet in the question itself. thx

Comment: @Anurag Actually, your code is still incomplete because it references variables that are defined elsewhere.

Comment: @Anurag And now it references a document we cannot see. And it has grown way beyond *minimal*.

Comment: @John - My simple purpose is to store multiple variables in one place and then later reference them in a loop. Mike has given me an example but when I try it, I get an empty output.

Comment: @Anurag, at the risk of being argumentative, that is the question you have asked, but no, it is not your purpose.  Binding a value of any kind to a variable and later accessing part or all of it is a *means to an end*, not an end in itself.  The more XSL you present the more I think it likely that there is a completely different approach to the transformation you want to perform, but I cannot suggest details because you refuse to present the information I would need to do so.  At this point, I have spent as much time on this as I can justify, so I simply wish you luck.

Answer (score 1):

> I would like to refer later like edgeDeviceArray[1]

That won't work for two reasons:

1. There's only one `edgeDeviceArray`. In order to refer to its first item, you would need to use something like `$edgeDeviceArray/item[1]`;
2. In XSLT 1.0, your variable is a *result tree fragment*, and must be converted to a *node-set* before its contents can be addressed by XPath.

Here's a minimized example:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:exsl="http://exslt.org/common"
extension-element-prefixes="exsl">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:variable name="myVar">
    <item>A</item>
    <item>B</item>
</xsl:variable> 

<xsl:template match="/">
    <result>
        <xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($myVar)/item[2]"/>
    </result>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Result**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<result>B</result>
```

Comment: <xsl:variable name="edgeDeviceArray">
          <Item><xsl:value-of select="$edgeDev1" /></Item>
                <Item><xsl:value-of select="$edgeDev2" /></Item>
         </xsl:variable> 
            
             
            <anurag><xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($edgeDeviceArray)/Item[1]" /></anurag>

Comment: Did U mean the above? I can't put template match as it is there outside. I am always getting empty output

Comment: @Anurag I am afraid I cannot help you with code that I cannot reproduce.

Comment: @Anurag My answer stands. `<xsl:value-of select="exsl:node-set($edgeDeviceArray)/Item[1]" />` should return the same as `<xsl:value-of select="$edgeDev1" />`.